# Как создать поддомен через php?

Tags: домен, php

Все привет!
Интересует вопрос, можно ли средствами php создать домен третьего уровня? И если можно, то как?
Спасибо :)

Comment: Cредствами php нет! С помощью htaccess да! Но зависит так же от хостера. Гуглите, пишите хостеру с этим вопросом!

Comment: **Palmervan** прав. Обращаться нужно к вашему хостеру.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете поступить так.

Прописать в настройка вашего регистратора запись типа A для всех поддоменов, указывающую на один ip-адрес

```
*.example.com       IN  A       x.x.x.x
```

где x.x.x.x - это ip-адрес вашего сервера. Все, что теперь нужно, это настроить редиректы так, чтобы поддомены перенаправлялись в нужное место.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([aA-zZ0-9])$  handle.php?user=$1
```

и

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.example.com
RewriteRule (.*)  handle.php?user=%1
```

Ну, и также возможно найти хостера, который предоставляет API, позволяющий прописывать записи динамически.

Answer (score -2):

Через PHP нет, поддомены создаются через панель управления хостинга сайта.